# Excel read Based on cell with range of values and pick value from different cell

Tags: excel, exception, vba

Hello I need help in Excel on the following scenario Please help

```
Column A             Column B             Column C           Column D
1-10                  $11
11-20                 $15
21-30                 $18
31-40                 $28
41-50                 $35
51-60                 $48
61-70                 $49
71-80                 $56
81-90                 $63
91-100                $70
```

if i enter 32 in Column C , column populates $28 , if i select 61 in Column C , Column populates $49 vice versa.
Please help 
Thank you,
Haider

Answer (score 1):

Place only the **lower** values in column **A**, not the range of values; put a lookup value in **C1** and in **D1** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C1,A1:A10,1))
```

[image]

Comment: I would take this formatting approach but simply do a VLOOKUP (D2=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,1)). This and the above answer accomplish the same thing, but VLOOKUP was made to simplify this equation. It will also make it easier for others, who are less excel oriented, to see what is happening.

Comment: @urdearboy I agree, using *VLOOKUP()* is an improvement.  I encourage you to post your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data as is with this array formula (complete with Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$10,MATCH(C1,--LEFT($A$1:$A$10,FIND("-",$A$1:$A$10)-1),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is building on Gary's Student's solution (equal alternative). Format your values down column A using the lower values of your range buckets as Gary suggested. If you intend to enter your look-up value in C1, use the following equation in D1:

```
=Vlookup(C1,A:B,2,1)
```

The equation will scan column A for the closest match to your C1 value and then return the corresponding value in column B.

Using the Index & Match function accomplishes the same thing, however, those functions tend to only be intuitive to *more advance Excel users*. The Vlookup (and Hlookup) were implemented in excel to simplify the Index/Match combination.